# how to get pic for each song? i come to know that its known as album art . i get song name , artist, album from my code but not album art

Tags: android

```
 String[] STAR = {"*"};

    Cursor cursor;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";


    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = 0;
            Drawable img;
            do {
                String songName = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

                path[i] = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                albumId = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                song.add(songName);
```

//above code works perfectly but this next line creates error
             String path =                                                                               cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
                    System.out.println(path);
                    i++;
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to get album art of songs :

```
public static Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context, Long album_id){
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    try{
          final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
          Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
          ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
          if (pfd != null){
              FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
              bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
              pfd = null;
              fd = null;
          }
      } catch(Error ee){}
      catch (Exception e) {}
      return bm;
    }
```

Comment: how to set this bitmap object as image in custom notification and list

Comment: the code is perfect and anyone want information how to use above code plz comment

Comment: @HarshRaval - Didn't get your first query, can you elaborate more?

Comment: i solved it by your code bro . chill your answer is perfect